# Bash script - Some commands don't work in sh file

Tags: bash, sed, cp

I have some troubles with my bash script. The end of my file doesn't work but every commands work outside the file. I have two strings as argument $1 and $2. $acl_line and $usebackend_line are numbers and they are good.

Here is my end file :

```
sed -i "$((acl_line+1))i \ \tacl\t\t is_$2_$1\t\thdr_com(host)\t-i $2.$1" /my_doc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
sed -i "$((usebackend_line+1))i \ \tuse_backend\t$2_$1\tif is_$2_$1" /my_doc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
echo -en "\nbackend $2_$1\n\tserver $2_$1 163.172.167.52:$3 maxconn 1024" >> /my_doc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

cp -r "./model/*" "./script/lp_domains/$1/$2/"
sed -i 's/lp_ports/$ports/g' "./script/lp_domains/$1/$2/my_doc.yml"
sed -i 's/lp_name/$2-$1/g' "./script/lp_domains/$1/$2/my_doc.yml"
```

Thanks for your anwsers :)

Comment: in the last two sed commands, `$ports` and `$2-$1` need to be substituted as bash variables or `$` is actually part of replacement string?

Answer (score 1):

If `$1` and `$2` should be interpolated, you cannot use single quotes.

Moreover, copying a file and then running `sed -i` on it is wasteful and error-prone.  Just run `sed` and perform your substitutions at the same time.

```
sed -i -e "$((acl_line+1))i \ \tacl\t\t is_$2_$1\t\thdr_com(host)\t-i $2.$1" \
    -e "$((usebackend_line+1))i \ \tuse_backend\t$2_$1\tif is_$2_$1" /my_doc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg \
    -e "\$a\
backend $2_$1\n\tserver $2_$1 163.172.167.52:$3 maxconn 1024" /my_doc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

# remove ./model/my_doc.yml; instead have a template ./my_doc.yml.in
cp -r "./model/*" "./script/lp_domains/$1/$2/"
sed -e "s/lp_ports/$ports/g" -e "s/lp_name/$2-$1/g" \
    my_doc.yml.in  >"./script/lp_domains/$1/$2/my_doc.yml"
```

(You should probably do something similar with `haproxy.cfg.in` actually.)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my errors. It was just permissions errors, Sed create some temporary files so i add permissions to my user. Thanks for your help !